# change rolename and static ip in azure python update_role

Tags: python, azure

The Azure Python API update_role doesn't provide way to update the role name and set static ip, are there any alternative ways to do these operations.

Answer (score 0):

The `update_role` function of `azure.servicemanagement.servicemanagementservice` for Python is wrapped the REST API [`Update Role`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157187.aspx). The role name is not an attribute of request body, so it could not update the role name, but you can set the static ip for the role via the parameter [`network_config`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/71ecaace918e50e2a3cb7cc1c19f8a8ab4336909/azure-servicemanagement-legacy/azure/servicemanagement/servicemanagementservice.py#L1485) for the tag `<StaticVirtualNetworkIPAddress>ip-address</StaticVirtualNetworkIPAddress>` in the request body of REST API.

However, I searched a [blog](https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/setting-a-webworker-role-name/) of a MS developer which introduce setting a Web/Worker Role Name via modify the [Role schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156212.aspx).